# USB camera software

Tags: open-source, camera

Could someone suggest me a advanced USB camera software, I intend to use it with a USB based sensor board for my Raspberry Pi module.

The purpose is to see microscopic entities. Therefore, I need functionalities such as exposure, brightness, frame, resolution, aspect ratio, still capture, video capture, timed still captures controls, etc. An example camera board is such as [this](https://www.e-consystems.com/13mp-autofocus-usb-camera.asp#Key-features).
[image: 1]

It would be very helpful if its a freeware ready to use version.

Answer (score 1):

You might try [guvcview](http://guvcview.sourceforge.net/), although that only works with cameras that present themselves as a USB Video Class device (most do these days unless they're highly specialized devices).  It's also a GUI specific option, so if you're doing embedded stuff, it may not be best.

Alternatively, you should be able to find a decent application that uses V4L2, although I don't have any specific recommendation for that as I don't use anything myself that doesn't work with guvcview, but there are options with V4L for both command-line and graphical interfaces.

As a third option, if you're controlling this from a Raspberry Pi, had you looked at the possibility of using a CSI connected camera module instead?  It's more likely you'll be able to get a camera that exactly fits your needs that way, and you can just talk to it directly with existing command-line tools.

Comment: I downloaded guvcview, is it only for debian/ linux ? I dont see any setup file from the download.

Comment: Try installing it through the system's package manager (probably `apt-get install guvcview` run as root should do it).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try [QtCAM](https://www.e-consystems.com/opensource-linux-webcam-software-application.asp) - Open Source UVC Linux Camera Software. This Qt Linux camera software application provides easier user interface for capturing and viewing video from devices supported by Linux UVC driver. It would also work with any V4L2 compatible device.